# Whether Aeroplane or Airplane?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Which word should i use, whether aeroplane or airplane? what is the meaning of these words else what is the difference between two if there?

P.S: please correct if my question is wrong or inappropriate to this site.

Comment: Airplane is AmE. Aeroplane is BrE. This is a basic question and likely to be closed. Check out http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/aeroplane

Comment: If we assume that learners do not know what the designations in dictionaries are that refer to different varieties of English, I don't think it's an off-topic question.

Comment: @CarSmack I did not do any effort. Oxford Dictionary is well known and searching for that word *defines* it clearly.

Comment: Hi @Maulik V! Yes, the dictionary you used is very clear in that it spells out American English and British English. What I mean is that some dictionaries use abbreviations for those terms, and the OP might not have known what they meant. In addition, I don't think that for all learners it is obvious that the meaning is exactly the same when a dictionary uses those terms to refer only to spelling differences. I'm just trying to give the benefit of the doubt to a user, you know, cut him some slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aeroplane%2Cairplane&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caeroplane%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cairplane%3B%2Cc0) answers your question nicely:

[image]

*Aeroplane* is an old form on the decline. It's not wrong but it's becoming obsolete fast. You'd likely use it to WWI era *aeroplanes* but you wouldn't call a jet fighter an *aeroplane* - currently it's almost exclusively an *airplane*.

Comment: The use of *aeroplane* is declining in British English, but it is still the preferred form (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aeroplane%2C+airplane&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caeroplane%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cairplane%3B%2Cc0). I suspect that *plane* is now the most common form in most varieties of English

Comment: @tunny In what varieties of English do you think plane is the most common form?

Comment: @CarSmack: Like most Brits (most Anglophones), if I use air travel to get somewhere I invariably *[travel] [by **plane** to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+aeroplane+to%2Cby+airplane+to%2Cby+plane+to&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20aeroplane%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20airplane%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20plane%20to%3B%2Cc0) [wherever I'm going]*.

Comment: I don't know. I would guess it's more common in Australia, Canada, Ireland New Zealand, the UK and the USA. Incidentally, I have just looked at BNC citations: *aeroplane(s)* - 741, *airplane(s)* - 105, *aircraft* - 6,072! I couldn't look for *plane* because of the other meanings of that word.

Comment: ngrams don't answer anything on their own. In this case, "airplane" is more common because it's the preferred term in the USA, whereas "aeroplane" is the preferred term in the UK. You'll notice that the USA has about five times the population of the UK and that "airplane" is about five times as common as "aeroplane".